# Dynamically eliminate html tags from Placeholder contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, placeholder

I don't know if it is possibile. I have to work with custom placeholders that i can't edit and  that take contents from DB. in the DB there is text with some html tags. I want to eliminate these tags, but i won't eliminate them from DB. So I have to eliminate them from the placeholder content.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you modify the text before it is placed in the placeholder?

Comment: tags means html tags??

Comment: I use the method .PlaceholderToBind. So i don't think.

Comment: Yeah i means html tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
Code

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
var body = "<p>test</p>";
var result = body.replace(regex, "");
alert(result);
```